# JavaScript: Assigning "this" to a prototype function

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I was wondering how we could properly bind "this" to an instance of an Object when creating a method on the prototype:

Example:

```
Array.prototype.myPush = function (element) {
    //call push on the instance of Array that calls this method
}

function push(array, element) {
    array[array.length] = element;
}
```

How could we get the first to work like the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a method on prototype, `this` is already bound to the object on which the method is called.

```js
Array.prototype.myPush = function(element) {
  this.push(element);
};

var arr = [1, 3, 4];
arr.myPush(10); // Call method on proto
console.log(arr);

function push(array, element) {
  array.myPush(element); // Same call from function
}

push(arr, 'Hello');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Oh, of course! I was getting confused when I wasn't getting a the new array returned to me. When I add a "return this;" statement at the end it behaves the same.